How to configure InstancePrincipalsAuthenticationDetailsProvider with an empty proxy
I am trying  configure InstancePrincipalsAuthenticationDetailsProvider with a cleared proxy. The equivalent would be to clear the JVM proxy settings before instantiating it. For example
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost","");  
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort","");  
InstancePrincipalsAuthenticationDetailsProvider instancePrincipalsAuthenticationDetailsProvider = InstancePrincipalsAuthenticationDetailsProvider.builder().build();    
.
.
.

I have tried this to no avail. I still get a 502 error
ClientConfigurator clientConfigurator = builder -\> {
ProxyConfiguration proxyConfiguration =
ProxyConfiguration.builder().proxy(Proxy.NO_PROXY).build();  
builder.property(StandardClientProperties.PROXY, proxyConfiguration);
};

instancePrincipalsAuthenticationDetailsProvider =
InstancePrincipalsAuthenticationDetailsProvider. builder().additionalFederationClientConfigurator(clientConfigurator)
.build();

Any code examples would be great. Thanks!
